# Evaluation of generalized Laguerre function integrals using orthogonality relations

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, mathematical-physics, orthogonality

*(NB - I am not asking to be spoon-fed with complete solutions, just pointing out any useful transformations, or giving general pointers would suffice.)*

The [orthogonality relation for generalized Laguerre functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials) is given as the following:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^\alpha \ e^{-x} \ L_n^\alpha (x) \ L_m^\alpha (x) \ dx = \frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha + n +1 \right)}{n!} \delta_{mn}$$

If we have to evaluate integrals in which we have $x^{(\alpha + k)}$ in the integrand instead of $x^{\alpha}$ as it occurs in the orthogonality relation, i.e. one is dealing with:

$$I =  \int_0^{\infty} x^{(\alpha + k)} \ e^{-x} \ L_n^\alpha (x) \ L_m^\alpha (x) \ dx \ \ \ \ \ ,$$

where $\alpha$ is a positive half integer.

How do we evaluate these type of integrals, in situations where:

- $k$ is a positive integer.
- $k$ is a negative integer.
- $k$ is a positive half-integer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can only provide the opposite, that is, the final answer without a clean derivation. The result is

> $$\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha + k} L_m^{(\alpha)} L_n^{(\alpha)} e^{-x} dx = \\ \frac {(-1)^n \,(m + \alpha)!} {n!} \sum_{i = 0}^m \frac {(-1)^i \,(i + k)! \,(i + k + \alpha)!} {i! \,(i + \alpha)! \,(m - i)! \,(i + k - n)!}, \\ m, n, 2k, \alpha - \frac 1 2 \in \mathbb N^0,$$

which has a closed form in terms of the regularized hypergeometric function ${_3\hspace{-1px}{\widetilde F}\hspace{-2px}_2}$. For $-k \in \mathbb N$, the answer is the same, but the $i$th term $a_i$ is understood as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} a_{i + \epsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any source for this, I mean, where did you find this?

Comment: I took the formula for the integral of a product of two Meijer G-functions (the Mellin transform of a polynomial doesn't exist, so the formula isn't applicable), formally wrote the resulting (non-existent) G-function as a sum of hypergeometrics and cancelled the singularities. As another possible route, you can write the Laguerre polynomials as sums with binomial coefficients, multiply the sums and integrate termwise. Then you get a sum of hypergeometrics evaluated at $1$. There are several questions on math.SE about simplifications of those, but I don't know of a general method.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am not conversant with many of the things you have mentioned, but I will try to do some reading and try to follow up. Thanks again :)